# stop select box multiple allowing users to select more than one option

Tags: jquery, html-select

I know this is a daft question but I have a select box with multiple='multiple' as I want it to appear as the box with the options rather than a drop down.  Is there any way to keep this look but prevent the user from selecting more than one option (like what happens on a normal drop down).  Using JQuery maybe.  I tried removing the multiple='multiple' and adding a height but this did not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

`<select size="n">`

?

Comment: To clarify, you'd *not* use the `multiple` attribute. And "n" should be replaced with the number of rows you want the box to have. Although you may be better off always just using size 2 and using CSS to specify the real height: `<select size="2" style="height:250px">`

Comment: just what I was after.  I didn't realise you could do this